# encrypting message in a text file python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read through a file and encrypt the message using my function.  I want to only encrypt words and leave everything else alone.  The file reading through is called plain.txt and I want to encrypt it in a new file called newPlain.txt. Also I need to justify how many shifts the cipher wants.

Here is my function:

```
# k is how many shifts you want
def CaeserCipher(string, k):

    upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower = 'abcdefgihjklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    newCipher = ''

    for letter in string:
        if letter in upper:
            if upper.index(letter) + k > 25:
                indexPosition = (upper.index(letter) + k) - 26
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = upper.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
        elif letter in lower:
            if lower.index(letter) + k > 25:
                indexPosition = (lower.index(letter) + k) - 26
                newCipher = newCipher + lower[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = lower.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + lower[indexPosition]

    return newCipher
```

this is what I have so far:

```
# main file
# reading file and encrypting text

f = open('plain.txt', "r+")

for line in f:
    newLine = CaeserCipher(line, 3)
    line.replace(line, newLine)





f.close()
```

Would I want to break it up into a list?  But then if so, how would I be able to put it back into the same spot?  If anyone has some ideas of how to go about this it would be greatly appreciated.

plain.txt: (it doesn't have to start with a alpha character, could start with a space too, or anything that isn't a letter.

Hello, My name is Ed.

How are you?

from- Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would grab individual words and map them to `CaeserCipher` (properly named `caesercipher`, only use `CapWords` for a Class as per PEP-8). The reason for this is one of your first bits: "I want to only encrypt words and leave everything else alone." Because of this, a little map/filter action sounds good.

```
# def isWord(word):
#     return all(ch.isalpha() for ch in word)
# oops I forgot that str.isalpha handles whole strings and not
# just characters. This is useless.

with open('plain.txt') as inf and open('encrypted.txt','w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        line = [caesercipher(word) if word.isalpha() else word for word in line.strip().split()]]
        outf.write(' '.join(line)+"\n")
```

Alternatively, you can redefine your `caesercipher` so it doesn't touch non-word words.

```
def caesercipher(string, k):
    upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower = 'abcdefgihjklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    if not string.isalpha():
        return string
    else:
        # apply your cipher, which honestly should be something using a deque
        # rotation building a str.translate mapping, but we'll keep it simple
        # for now. Let me know if you want more info on that though.
```

And then skip the check in your `line = [caesercipher(word) ...` statement in the first code block I posted.

OPTIONAL: DEQUE REPLACEMENT

a `deque` is basically a circular list. You can `rotate` it so `deque(['1','2','3']).rotate(1) == deque(['3','1','2'])`. You can use this to build a pretty damn efficient Caeser cipher like so:

```
from collections import deque
from copy import copy # just to save time
def caesercipher(string, k):
    upper = deque("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    lower = deque("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    resultupper = copy(upper)
    resultupper.rotate(-k)
    resultlower = copy(lower)
    resultlower.rotate(-k)
    dict_for_trans = dict(zip(upper,resultupper))
    dict_for_trans.update(dict(zip(lower,resultlower)))

    transdict = str.maketrans(dict_for_trans)

    return string.translate(transdict)
```

The nice thing about this method is that `str.translate` is very very fast, and the dictionary you provide it ensures that nothing EXCEPT what you personally define will be touched. None of these `list.index` calls that take forever, everything is hashed and done quickly. It's also useful because for `k > 26`, it still works! `caesercipher("abc",27) -> 'bcd'`

Comment: Also as a side note, if you `import string` and change the name of your parameter in `caesercipher(string, k)`, you can do `upper = string.ascii_uppercase` and `lower = string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the lines, just make sure to append a newline when you write them.

```
with open('plain.txt','r+') as plainFile:
    lines = plainFile.read().splitlines()

with open('newPlain.txt', 'w') as newFile:
    for line in lines:
        newFile.write(CaesarCipher(line, 3) + "\n")
```

Which will iterate through the lines, encrypt the lines, and then write them, all sequentially.